# The function being called to sum or get product is incorrect

Tags: c++, class, switch-statement

When I run this function the sum or the product is grossly wrong. I put in 2 and 3 for the inputs and got like a negative a million. The same is for the product too. Im going to add another cout statement after i ask for which calculation they want to do to make it more natural.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class basicCalculator {
public:
int add(int x,int y) {
    return add1 + add2;
}

int multiply(int x,int y) {
    return multiply1*multiply2;
}

private:
int add1;
int add2;
int multiply1;
int multiply2;

};

int main() {
cout << "What mathematical action do you want?" << endl;
cout << "Press '1' to add two numbers, '2' to multiply two numbers" << endl;

int method;

cin >> method;

int value1;
cin >> value1;
int value2;
cin >> value2;

basicCalculator bc;

switch (method) {
case 1:
    cout << "The sum is " << bc.add(value1, value2) << endl;
    break;
case 2:
    cout << "The product is " << bc.multiply(value1, value2) << endl;
}
```

}

Comment: You're using the uninitialized class variables in the methods. Use the parameters instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside your `add` and `multiply` methods you are using (uninitalized) member variables instead that the actual arguments.

Try with:

```
int add(int x, int y) { return x + y; }
```

A suggestion: `add` and `multiply` don't need an object state at all, they could be static, I don't see any reason for all the member variables you declared.

Answer (score 1):

Freddy, in your functions you must use the named parameters for your calculations.
So, NOT

```
int add(int x,int y) {
    return add1 + add2;
}
```

but rather

```
int add(int x,int y) {
    return x + y;
}
```

Same problem with multiply.